# JPA Entity has null object references

Tags: java, jpa, servlets, jakarta-ee, gwt

Just working on a Java EE application with a GWT client when I discovered something a bit odd. A particular object I have is created with a few null columns in the database table. Not much of a problem until I perform an update. This update is triggered by a servlet. As soon as the update is done, I perform a Remote Procedure Call (RPC) to refresh the grid. This is where the problem is: All object references (references to other entities) are all null and the code breaks on the server-side.

What I've tried:
I've tried performing a merge on every single entity after I get a list from the JPQL query. This still leaves the object references as null.

I don't understand what happens behind the scenes to cause this (this happens only on the entity updated by the servlet). And only a server restart solves the problem.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: Please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example, and update your question then. In short: do not write an essay explaining what you (want to) do, **show your code** instead (what have you tried so far).

Comment: @JozefChocholacek thanks. But this is probably the least I can break it down to without complicating the question and without pasting an entire project here on SO.

Comment: _and the code breaks on the server-side_ sounds like a good place to start with. Any stacktrace and/or code snippet where the problem occurs would give some light on it.